# Apache Echarts: include default behaviour when implementing event handler

Tags: angular, echarts

Take this example: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-link

In this portion of code:

```
myChart.on('updateAxisPointer', function (event) {
    const xAxisInfo = event.axesInfo[0];
    if (xAxisInfo) {
      const dimension = xAxisInfo.value + 1;
      myChart.setOption({
        series: {
          id: 'pie',
          label: {
            formatter: '{b}: {@[' + dimension + ']} ({d}%)'
          },
          encode: {
            value: dimension,
            tooltip: dimension
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

the "updateAxisPointer" event handler got override. Now the custom logic is run, but not the default one.
You can try to set the `showSymbol: false`: with the custom handler, when you hover on the series, no point is shown, without the custom handler, when hovering, the points are shown.

I want to use the default behaviour AND the custom one, how can I accomplish that?